# Maven site-plugin remove or change Parent Project Link

Tags: java, maven

I am deploying a Maven site using mvn site:deploy, and the deploy works correctly, but the link to the parent project does not.  [image]

The url the link points to is ../index.html
Where is it pulling this url from?

Is it possible to change this url?

If not can I just remove the Parent Project link?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Which version of Maven? Have you run `site:stage`? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html Have you looked at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-159 ?

Comment: Im using maven 3.1.1 for Windows.  I looked at the links you provided, but unfortunatly they do not seem to address my specific problem of changing or removing the "Parent Project" link